# Is there anything like React Fragment in VueJS, NuxtJS?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to group a list of children in Nuxt just like we do in React with `<React.Fragment>`. I don't want to use an HTML `div` as it's adding extra nodes to the DOM.

**Code Sample:**

```html
<template>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <navbar/>
    <nuxt/>
    <Footer/>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Footer from "@/components/Footer/Footer";

export default {
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Footer
  }
}
</script>
```

I want to remove `<div id="wrapper">` to something like we do in React as `<React.Fragment>`.

Comment: <template></template>

Comment: @JayLi You mean `<template><template></template></template>` ?

Comment: there should be only one root child in template. Its limitation of vue2.

Answer (score 2):

### Vue v3

<strike>Vue v3 supports multi-root components out-of-the-box. However it does not support deeply nested fragments.</strike>

**UPDATE**: You can nest `<template>`!

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <template>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Vue already has a `<Fragment>`: it's `<template>`. It doesn't produce a DOM element and you can use any structural directive on it (`v-for`, `v-if`, etc...).

Comment: But root template can't have multiple nodes nested and that's what OP was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official solution from the Vue team yet but there is a npm module `vue-fragment` created by [Julien Barbay](https://github.com/y-nk) that will enable the use of `<Fragment>` in vue templates.

```html
<Fragment>
  <element / >
  <element / >
  <element / >
</Fragment>
```

Will output

```html
<!--Fragment-->
  <element / >
  <element / >
  <element / >
<!--Fragment-->
```

I'm not sure what the purpose of the html comment is - but the output is now more semantic.

This post explains more in details: https://blog.logrocket.com/fragments-in-vue-js/

Comment: There is no need for `<Fragment>` in Vue. You already have `<template>`.